# Altering multiprocessing lists

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

I've recently come across a strange behaviour in Python 2.7.

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> lst = mp.Manager().list()
>>> lst.append([1,2])
>>> lst.append([3,4])
>>> print(lst)
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> lst[0][1] = 123
>>> print(lst)
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Huh? Why the first element of the multiprocessing list wasn't changed? It works fine with ordinary lists!

Let's try it a different way.

```
>>> lst[0] = [1,123]
>>> print(lst)
[[1, 123], [3, 4]]
```

OK, so at least I have a workaround. But why the assigment `lst[0][1] = 123` in the first snippet did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to work on your issue and here is what I've come across:

> Note Modifications to mutable values or items in dict and list proxies will not be propagated through the manager, because the proxy has no way of knowing when its values or items are modified. To modify such an item, you can re-assign the modified object to the container proxy:

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202278/cannot-append-items-to-multiprocessing-shared-list).

So it seems it's not the matter with data structure itself but with managing it. So, I've created a process according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def targ(*args, **kwargs):
  print('Args: {}'.format(args[0]))
  args[0][0].pop()
  args[0][0].append(123)
  print('Args: {}'.format(args[0]))

manager = mp.Manager()
lst = manager.list()
lst.append([1, 2])
lst.append([3, 4])

print(lst)

proc = mp.Process(target=targ, args=(lst,))
proc.start()
proc.join()

print(lst)
```

Giving me following result:

```
$ python3 main.py 
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
Args: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
Args: [[1, 123], [3, 4]]
[[1, 123], [3, 4]]
```

No changes occureed when I've tried assiging with `args[0][0][1] = 123` so one workaround or antoher will be necessary.

Comment: It makes sense when I think about it now. Thanks!